# why my docker image bigger than du -hd 1 /

Tags: docker, docker-image

when i use `openjdk:8u171-alpine` to build my java application.

The image size is bigger than what i think.

The `openjdk:8u171-alpine` is only 103MB, and my test jar file about 30MB.

But my new docker images is 160MB.

I don't know why.So I use  `docker run --rm -it  openjdk:8u171-alpine  du -hd 1` .The output  is as follows

```
4.0K    ./home
4.0K    ./srv
1.6M    ./etc
4.0K    ./root
2.8M    ./lib
4.0K    ./mnt
95.8M   ./usr
16.0K   ./media
0       ./sys
0       ./dev
224.0K  ./sbin
784.0K  ./bin
4.0K    ./run
0       ./proc
4.0K    ./tmp
68.0K   ./var
101.3M  .
```

and when I run same in my docker images

```
4.0K    /home
4.0K    /srv
1.6M    /etc
8.0K    /root
2.8M    /lib
4.0K    /mnt
95.8M   /usr
16.0K   /media
0       /sys
0       /dev
224.0K  /sbin
784.0K  /bin
4.0K    /run
0       /proc
4.0K    /tmp
68.0K   /var
29.8M   /app
4.0K    /logs
131.1M  /
```

It only 131.1MB,
but when I use `docker images`  the output shows 160MB

```
d3ac9dcbe21c   20 minutes ago   165MB
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8u171-alpine
MAINTAINER zhujiaxin<783725554@qq.com>
ENV LOGLEVEL=info
VOLUME ["/logs"]
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY /target/$JAR_FILE app.jar
RUN chmod 775 app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
CMD []
EXPOSE 8080
```

My jar file only 30M

Comment: when I save image to tar.gz and unzip it. I find it have two layer both have app.jar.so the image is 160M,but i don't know why. whether  my dockerfile  wrong?

Comment: What does `docker history` say?  Does the `RUN chmod` command wind up making an additional copy of the jar file?  (Is it necessary at all?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker layered filesystem is copy-on-write, and that copy is on a file level, not individual filesystem blocks. That means a change to a permission bit on a file with a chmod results in copying the entire file to a new layer:

```
COPY /target/$JAR_FILE app.jar
RUN chmod 775 app.jar
```

The result is a 30MB file would take up 2x that space, once for each layer, with the different permissions. Ideally, you'd fix the file permissions at the source to avoid the need to chmod the file. Then you'd only need the COPY step without the added chmod in a RUN:

```
COPY /target/$JAR_FILE app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

when i change dockerfile to

```
FROM openjdk:8u171-alpine
MAINTAINER zhujiaxin<783725554@qq.com>
ENV LOGLEVEL=info
VOLUME ["/logs"]
RUN mkdir /app && chmod 775 /app
WORKDIR /app
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY /target/$JAR_FILE app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
CMD []
EXPOSE 8080
```

the new images is 134M,so when run some command,run it before file copy.

new layer will copy file from your dictionary.