# How to reduce container image size when use no-root users?

Tags: docker

In my another question [why my docker image bigger than du -hd 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661876/why-my-docker-image-bigger-than-du-hd-1/69663451#69663451) .

I find when i use command like  `chmod` or `chown` to make docker image,the size of image will be double, the dictory in docker layer save twice.

But i also find docker no-root user issue in bitnami websit [why use no-root user image](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/work-with-non-root-containers/)

Today,I want use user app in my container, but an error occur.`no permission`

But the image size will be bigger again.

What can i do?

In bitnami's image they use curl to download file,but i use `ADD` and `COPY` in Dockerfile.

Does `ADD` and `COPY` can change the user in dockerfile?

Comment: To provide more assistance, we'd need a [mcve].

Comment: Often having the files owned by root is correct – you don't want the application to be able to accidentally overwrite its own code or static assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `COPY`, there is a `--chown` flag:

```
COPY --chown=user src dest
```

This is described in the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy).

The layered filesystem is copy-on-write at a file level, so any change to the file, including metadata like permissions and ownership, will result in a copy of the entire file to the new layer.